# rsync FROM EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, rsync, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I'm trying to copy data from an EC2 instance to a remote host and am wondering why my rsync command hangs.

I've generated a key-pair using `ssh-keygen` on the EC2 instance and then added the `id_rsa.pub` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host. When I run rsync, the command hangs. No permission denied/could not resolve hostname error or even output. I can ssh from other hosts and also rsync when on the remote host from the ec2 instance.

On the EC2 instance,

```
$ ping remote_host
PING remote_host (re.mo.te.ip) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from re.mo.te.ip (re.mo.te.ip): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.0 ms
$ rsync -avze "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" /absolute/path/to/source remote_user@remote_host:/target
...hangs
$ rsync -avze "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa" /absolute/path/to/source remote_user@re.mo.te.ip:/target
...hangs
```

As a note, I tried to `ssh-copy-id` the EC2 instance's public key before manually copying it into the remote host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, but received a `Connection timed out` error. This makes me think a connection is made w/ my rsync command, but for some reason there isn't a reply from the remote host.

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote_user@remote_host
sudo ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote_user@remote_host
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host remote_user@remote_host port 22: Connection timed out
```

My question is - should I be able to run my rsync from an EC2 instance if I've generated my key-pair and added them correctly to my remote host? Or, are there other factors (I've read about [security groups and firewalls](https://blog.learningtree.com/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/))? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> ssh: connect to host remote_user@remote_host port 22: Connection timed out

> Or, are there other factors (I've read about security groups and firewalls)?

Your error message does not mean the key was refused. The client didn't even reach the point of *offering* the key. More precisely, "Connection timed out" means that the OS did not receive a response to the TCP handshake – it failed before it could even begin speaking SSH.

This means that there is a firewall somewhere along the way which is allowing only ICMP packets to pass through, but blocking TCP. Most likely, it is on the "server" side – i.e. not on *your* EC2 instance, but rather on the `remote_host` that you're trying to reach. (Typically firewalls are set up to block incoming connections but allow outgoing ones, from their perspective.)

Contact your remote_host's owners and tell them your EC2 instance's public IP addresses. They'll be able to investigate their own logs and firewall rules better than outsiders could.

Comment: Allowed ICMP, but blocked TCP makes a lot of sense, especially considering the ping utility works. I'll investigate w/ the owners and come back if that resolves the issue. Thanks!